# UIWebView Text Highlighting solution

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, selection, highlighting

Has anyone found a solution for highlighting ***user-selected*** blocks of text in a UIWebView?

I have a partial solution in place, however I have been unable to get it to work when the selection includes multiple elements in the DOM.  In that case, I can find and highlight the first element in the selection, but javascript seems unable to tell me where the end of the selection is in this case.

It may be that I just don't understand the selection objects completely.  It's difficult to find good documentation on them.

Comment: are you able to highlight and save selected text in UIWebView. I want to highlight and save the highlights. I have database but no luck to do it though i have tried many things.

Comment: I've been working with iOS for years now and this was the single most difficult thing I've done in it, but yes I did get it to work eventually. Tim's comment below was the key to really get it to work reliably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.execCommand("HiliteColor")`. I answered a similar question recently:

[Making Selection & Adding tag dynamically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597989/making-selection-adding-tag-dynamically-in-javascript/7599079#7599079)

Regarding documentation, MDN is pretty good for [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) and [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range), although it doesn't really go into detailed examples.

Comment: That is fantastic.  I wasn't aware of the execCommand method.  Thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to find these highlights again programmatically... but that's a completely different issue heh.

Comment: Problem is that the code also highlighted everything in the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I found perfect solution for this issue.Follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644130/2852281) Link.

Good Luck

Comment: interesting... going to have to try this for a more maintainable solution.  thanks for the followup.